# Retrieving the used modifiers on button click with QtQuick 2.9

Tags: qml, mouseevent

I've got that pure QML application working on QtQuick 2.9.

I'm trying to retrieve the keyboard modifier used during the mouseclick.

From QtQuick 2.15, I could write this:

```
Button {
    text: "button"
    onClicked: {
        if ((mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) && (mouse.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier)) {
            doSomething();
    } else {
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

But the [MouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html) isn't available in QtQuick 2.9.

What's the alternative ?

Comment: What makes you think "MouseEvent isn't available in QtQuick 2.9"?

Comment: Here's a link to older [docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-mouseevent.html) that shows MouseEvent still existed then.

Comment: On one hand I probably misinterpreted the "Import Statement: import QtQuick 2.15" on the MouseEvent document page. On the other hand, when I click on the button, my code is throwing "ReferenceError: mouse is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Button's `clicked` signal does not provide a MouseEvent (no matter what version of Qt you're using). The clicked signal could be generated via the keyboard too, so it wouldn't make sense to provide a MouseEvent. You will need to create a MouseArea and handle the events yourself to do what you want.

```
Button {
    id: button

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent

        onPressed: {
            if ((mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) && (mouse.modifiers & Qt.ShiftModifier)) {
                doSomething();
            } else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
    }
}
```